# Any advantage to the script version of Google Adwords' conversion tracking code?

Tags: google-ads

Google Adword has an HTML snippet to track conversions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 12345;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "someopaqueid";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/12345/?label=opaque&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

It is composed of two parts:

1. For clients supporting javascript, an inline script that sets variables, plus loading a reporting script.
2. For other clients, an image tag.

As far as I can see, the image tag has some advantages:

1. It works on all browsers.
2. It is asynchronous.
3. It's shorter to have only this version, compared to both this and the js version.

Any reason not to drop the `<noscript>` tag and just use the image conversion snippet directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image will have more limitations than javascript code.  The image can also be more easily blocked using browser plugins.

When you use the javascript you can use its api to track different variables such as order items, and total.

Good practice is to include both.